# Prestashop 1.5.5 getting image error on importing csv file

Tags: prestashop-1.5

i am getting image importing error on importing csv file

```
Error copying image: http://www.myimages.com/20131230-capture0302.jpg
```

please help me if someone solve the error before.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open the file classes/Tools.php and on row 1408, which is:

```
return @copy($source, $destination, $stream_context);
```

remove the last parameter, so it becomes:

```
return @copy($source, $destination);
```

and try again.